# Swift: Segue to another view when Map View is tapped

Tags: swift, mkmapview, segue

I would like to perform a segue to another view once a map view is tapped like when you check a location and tap on map on instagram, or like in foursquare.

I could not connect map view itself to another view directly like we do in buttons, and I don't want to perform segue when callout button is tapped.

I found a workaround by placing an invisible button into mapView, and performing segue when the button is tapped(user thinks mapView is tapped)

But I would like to know if there is a better solution for it, without a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
   let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapHandler(_:)))
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    @objc func tapHandler(_ gestureReconizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {


       // let location = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
       // coordinatte of taplocation
      // let coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

      // **you can navigate or perform Your Actions there**

    }
```